# jstree: Cannot get the containing folder of a leaf node

Tags: directory, parent, jstree

I've been struggling with this problem for days now...

I need to get the folder(node of rel='folder' id witch contains the leaf node (node of rel='default') I want to delete.

My server side deletes nodes from the DB based on the type.  For folders, not a problem, for leafs, I need the container folder's id to be able to delete the leaf in it.

I've tried various scenario and they were all catastrophic, returning undef or -1.

Even the most popular way:

```
(data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj)==-1?'root_node':data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj).attr('id'));
```

is always returning -1 for all the leaf nodes I'm trying to delete from wherever in the tree.

here's some more code:

```
.bind("remove.jstree", function (e, data) {
    data.rslt.obj.each(function () {
         var node = data.rslt.obj;

         console.log('rel:'+node.parent("li[rel='folder']").attr("id")); // always undef
         var node2=$("#demo").jstree("_get_parent", data.rslt.obj.attr("id"));
         console.log("another try:"+node2.attr("id"));  always undef
         var node_parent=(data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj)==-1?'root_node':data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj).attr('id'));
         console.log('node_parent for ' + data.rslt.obj.attr("id") + ':'+node_parent);// always -1
         var parents = [];
        $(data.rslt.obj).parents('li').each(function () {
            parents.push({ id: $(this).attr("id"), description: $(this).children("a").text() });
        });
        console.log('nb of parents:'+parent.length); // always 0;
        $.ajax({
            async : false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: "ajaxTree.php",
            data : { 
                "operation" : "remove_node", 
                "id" : this.id.replace("node_",""),
                 "type" : data.rslt.obj.attr("rel"),
                 "parent": node_parent
            }, 
            success : function (r) {
                if(!r.status) {
                    //data.inst.refresh();
                    $.jstree.rollback(data.rlbk);
                }
            }
        });

    });
})
```

thanks for leaving a note of what you think could work, I'll try it, promissed :D

Comment: Why don't you add "container" id to your leaf? Just a quick thought.

Comment: this could be a option. I could modify the id to include the parent folder's id like 'node_123_parent_321 but that imply heavy reengeering of all the ajax calls where the id were used like create_node, delete_node etc... Use og regexp would be necessary to get both values.

Comment: Did you try `https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jstree/wHIT4gIdcIY` from https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jstree/wHIT4gIdcIY

Comment: but i will still remeber this solution if there's nothing else to do.  Thanks Radek :)

Comment: yes Radek I tried to console.log that methode (see code bellow):)

Comment: It's a quick dirty solution. All leaves will have 'not necessary' attribute and it might make your tree heavy to load. If your tree is not big I would go so anything that works :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use "data.inst" - the tree instance 
and "_get_parent" to get the parent: 

data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj);
```

This info found in [jstree groups](http://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jstree/wHIT4gIdcIY)